# Advanced search term in php and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a **MySql** table contain a title field.

Suppose a user enter a term in an input textbox.

Now I want to select rows whose title field has one of the following states:

1) its title is exactly the same as term : `"sugar">>"sugar"`

2) one of the words of its title is like the term : `"pretty flower" >> "rose flower"`

3) its title is from the same Word family as that term (term is root word of those) : `"biology" >> "biography, biodegradable, symbiotic"`

I'm using laravel. if can suggest any solution for that , Would be great

Comment: 1st two use the like condition in mysql. 
3rd one How do you define root word? You need to define root word criteria and use a Like condition on top of the root word.

Comment: Have you investigated `FULLTEXT` search?  You should know that word stemming (what you call word families) is a *hard* problem, and you may need a search program like Lucene or Sphinx if you want to do it acceptably well.

Answer (score 3):

This was an easy solution until you mentioned word family...

However, this is something that is still achievable. It's about how you approach it.

You'll start by using the `like` condition in MySQL.

You can read more about it on the MySQL Website relating to [**Pattern Matching**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Here's an example of that:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field1 LIKE '%searchTerm%';`

In terms of getting results by "word family", you may want to consider adding tags to the result.

Add a `tags` field in the table and add an array of tags that would relate to the "word family".

Your query would then look something like this:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field1 LIKE '%searchTerm%' OR field2 LIKE '%searchTerm%';`

You'll need to loop through the array of tags to find what matches, if at all.

Just my approach to ***get started***.

In terms of how to do this is [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), your query may look something like this, according to their [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects)

```
$results = DB::table('table1')
            ->where('myfield', 'like', '%searchterm%')
            ->get();
```

I surely hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: W3Schools?  Friends don't let friends....  Seriously, it's outdated and often wroing.

Comment: HA while I 100% agree... we're talking about a basic like condition in MySQL. W3Schools happens to have done that one correctly for the most part.

Comment: OK, then, as long as people know that **everything on the interent is true**!

Comment: I do not understand what you mean " *Add a tags field in the table and add an array of tags that would relate to the word family* ". Can you explain more?

Comment: You will add a field in the table called tags. It doesn't really matter what you call it. Call it "Word Family" if you want. Then just put an array of words that could be in the word family.

Comment: But in this case I must to know all word families of searched term. right ?while in many cases this is not possible. in fact I must to have a dictionary of that words already.

Comment: You would already need to know those words, yes. As I said, this is just a step in the right direction.